# DOB menu that opens in middle of list with overflow shown - Age restricted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a solution to create a scrollable DOB selector menu (one for month/day/and year) that opens in the middle of the list with the date current year - 18, using HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery, or bootstrap. I have been struggling to find a solution that allows a menu to open in the middle options with the top overflow still visible. I've seen some solutions to get the current year - 18 but none with the middle opening.

I'm starting to question if this is even possible and only an option with year select menu for the iPhone.

[Rough idea on what I am looking to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQoQO.png)

I'm also interested in hearing any alternative ideas you guys would have to have a quicker and more accessible way to have users input their DOB's, maybe something like the IOS Date picker but a desktop alternative.

What I have so far, basic DOB dropdown

```
<select name="DOBMonth">
    <option> - Month - </option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<select name="DOBDay">
    <option>Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="DOBYear">
    <option>Year</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>  
</select>
</div>
</body>`
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried as far as jQuery / javascript? This is totally possible, BTW.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fkeu5co4/ Here is something almost identical to what we have running in local prototypes. But the current build does not have any age restriction currently running.